# Calculating the volume of a cone using $\int_D f = \int_K \big[\int_{h(x)}^{g(x)} \ f(x,y) \ dy \big] \ dx$ : $x\in \mathbb{R^n}, y \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

There are various ways to calculate the volume of a cone. The one that I am trying is by evaluating the following integral $$\text{V} = \int_{x^2+y^2 \le a^2} \int_{0}^{\frac{h}{a} \sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}} \ 1 \ dz \ dK = \frac23 \pi a^2 h$$ which is twice as the expected one! Where do I do wrong?

PS I got $z$ by using some trigonometric; as $\dfrac{z^2}{h^2} = \dfrac{a^2-x^2-y^2}{a^2}.$ I guess that here $z$ is not like a 'normal' function of $(x,y)$ different from types like infinite paraboloid but even if so I don't know how it is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $\dfrac{z^2}{h^2} = \dfrac{a^2-x^2-y^2}{a^2}$ is wrong. The correct one is $\dfrac{z}{h} = \dfrac{a-\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}{a}$ which gives the correct answer $1/3 \pi a^2 h$.

Answer (score 1):

That region over which you are integrating is no cone at all. It's the top half of an ellipsoid.

You will get the value that you're after computing the integral$$\int_{-a}^a\int_{-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\int_{\frac ha\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^h1\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx.$$Here, my cone is$$\left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\,\middle|\,x^2+y^2\leqslant a^2\wedge\frac{h^2}{a^2}(x^2+y^2)\leqslant z^2\leqslant h^2\wedge0\leqslant z\right\}.$$

Comment: ${z^2}/{h^2} = (a^2-x^2-y^2)/{a^2}$ and $(1-z/h)^2 = (x^2+y^2)/{a^2}$ comes from the same theorem of trigonometric on the same object, but I don't understand why the latter gives an ellipsoid; both equations are also squared both use same $z$..

Comment: $$\frac{z^2}{h^2}=\frac{a^2-x^2-y^2}{a^2}\iff a^2z^2=(ah)^2-h^2x^2-h^2y^2\iff h^2x^2+h^2y^2+a^2z^2=(ah)^2.$$Is this an ellipsoid or not?

Comment: Of course it is but I derived it from a triangle as an intersection a plane through z-axis and the cone. So **how** it comes an ellipsoid?!

Comment: The book says "..the cone ${\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3}|x^2+y^2\le a^2, 0 \le z \le h/a^2(a^2-x^2-y^2) }\}$" for hint and I don't know how it deduce $z$?

Comment: @Edi Then the hint contains a mistake.

Comment: Yes, but ignoring the book I derived ${z^2}/{h^2} = (a^2-x^2-y^2)/{a^2}$ myself from a triangle comes from the intersection of the plane with the **cone** and still gives an ellipsoid!! And I couldn't find out a **reason** yet for why it gives an ellipsoid when the object is a cone?

Comment: @Edi I understand that, but if you don't show us how your argument, nobody will be able to tell where the error is.

Comment: I don't know how to draw a triangle on MSE, but I explain: intersection of the plane containing the z-axis with the cone is a triangle with base $a$ and height $h$. Draw a line parallel to the height from a point on the base with distance $\sqrt(x^2+y^2)$ from origin and call its size $z$. Then two equations ${z^2}/{h^2} = (a^2-x^2-y^2)/{a^2}$ and $(1-{z}/{h})^2 = (x^2+y^2)/{a^2}$ both hold. But the latter gives the correct answer, esp. consider both Eqs. when limited to $x=0$ ...

Comment: ... : the first gives an ellipse!! and the second one gives line (which is expected so). Also $(1-{z}/{h})^2 = (x^2+y^2)/{a^2}$ results $1/3 \pi a^2 h$ when evaluating vol.

Comment: I found it out! I posted the answer. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Your dealing with the equation $\dfrac{z^2}{h^2} = \dfrac{a^2-x^2-y^2}{a^2}$ is wrong, try with
$$\left(1-\dfrac{z}{h}\right)^2 = \dfrac{x^2+y^2}{a^2}.$$

Comment: I tried with $\left(1-\dfrac{z}{h}\right)^2 = \dfrac{x^2+y^2}{a^2}$ and it gives $1/3$. But how $\dfrac{z^2}{h^2} = \dfrac{a^2-x^2-y^2}{a^2}$ is wrong?! Same triangle same theorem..

Comment: Let $x=0$ in your equation, then you have a circle (ellipse) equation not a line

Comment: Yes again you are right! But I don't understand how $\dfrac{z^2}{h^2} = \dfrac{a^2-x^2-y^2}{a^2}$ gives a wrong result (i.e. circle) when limited to $x=0$ though it comes from the same trigonometric theorem!

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean that. Of course it must be a line when limited to any line on plane through the origin; my question is that ${z^2}/{h^2} = (a^2-x^2-y^2)/{a^2}$ must also give a line when the same limit applies but it fails and why? ${z^2}/{h^2} = (a^2-x^2-y^2)/{a^2}$ has come from same rule as $(1-\dfrac{z}{h})^2 = (x^2+y^2)/{a^2}.$ but it fails when testing a 'boundary' evaluation..

Comment: You should find the problem intuitively yourself. I try to show you with online software, wait . . .

Comment: With wolfram alpha let $h=25$ and $a=9$ . http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot3D+%7B5+Sqrt%5B9+-+x%5E2+-+y%5E2%5D%2F3,+0%7D,+%7Bx,+-2,+2%7D,+%7By,+-2,+2%7D+%5D

Comment: With command `Plot3D{5 Sqrt[9-x^2-y^2]/3, 0}, {x,-2,2}, {y,-2,2}]`

Comment: @Edi did you try with that?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't find out a reason yet for why it gives an ellipsoid when the object is a cone?

Comment: Sorry. I gave you the true equation and I can't enlightened you dear. I think it's better you try more to find it yourself. This will be worthwhile.

Comment: Yes, the equation you gave it the only answer fits what I asked (the original integral in the title); I will try for the mentioned contradiction. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

We need 3 constants $ (a,h,z_1):$

Equation of right circular cone with $z_1$ apex shift

$$\frac{r}{z-z_1}=\frac{a}{h}$$ or squaring,

$$ r^2=x^2+y^2= (z-z_1)^2(a/h)^2.$$